# using the pe_accounts module with hiera

Tags: puppet, hiera

I need to be able to manage user accounts using pe_accounts and hiera. This page:
http://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/accounts_class.html#usage-example
says I can create a module like site_accounts and add this text

```
class {'pe_accounts':
  data_store => yaml,
}
```

to site_accounts/manifests/init.pp
and then install this syntax

```
---
sysop:
  locked: false
  comment: System Operator
  uid: '700'
  gid: '700'
  groups:
  - admin
  - sudonopw
```

into a file named /var/lib/hiera/pe_accounts_users_hash.yaml

and this will be enough to add the user sysop. But it's not, of course. 
I did add the below syntax to hiera.conf

```
:hierarchy:
  - "common"
  - "pe_accounts_users_hash"
  - "pe_accounts_group_hash"
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find class pe_accounts for vmtest2.lala.kaka.org
```

Comment: The problem is not with your data - it's with Puppet not finding the `pe_accounts` class. **Are** you using Puppet Enterprise?

Comment: Possibly relevant discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/puppet-users/wP-jjdRy3Os/P5jlyGgbfBsJ