# Does puppetlabs' pe_accounts module support multiple system users with gid 0?

Tags: puppet

I'm using pe_accounts to maintain Red Hat system accounts and I've run into a problem.

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Duplicate declaration: Group[root] is already declared; cannot redeclare at /opt/puppet/share/puppet/modules/pe_accounts/manifests/user.pp:97
```

Several system users have a gid of 0 and the module seems not to support this.

Why would that be?

Comment: Whatever happened to your [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500452/using-the-pe-accounts-module-with-hiera)? Similar to that one, your interpretation seems to miss the point - duplicate user ID's are not the issue. You have a `group { "root": }` somewhere in your manifest, and **that** somehow clashes with the module.

Comment: I see. I recommend you review all your declarations of `pe_account::user` and try to find out by which logic the `Group[root]` gets declared in the indicated file.

Comment: Oh, I need to manage_groups and add the "shared" groups to pe_accounts_groups_hash.yaml. D'oh.

Comment: OK, I have added all my groups to pe_accounts_groups_hash.yaml. Now I'm getting this error:

Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: can't convert String into Hash at /opt/puppet/share/puppet/modules/pe_accounts/manifests/groups.pp:21

Comment: Looks like the create_resources in pe_accounts is broken, or I need to know how to re-implement it in my module.

Comment: My wrapper class looks like this: http://pastie.org/9347257

Comment: Or perhaps your YAML is malformed?